# Question on how to add strings using Python if conditional statements

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have a question.

I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

I want to add a specific character in the middle of a string using a python ‘if’ statement.

For example,

When I change **January 1, 2021** to a string, I want to convert 2020011 (7 letters) to 20200101 (8 letters).

This is my code I have tried

```
df2['date']=df2['date'].astype(str)
x = df2['date'].str.len()
def date_changing(x) :
    if x == 7: return df2.date.astype(str).apply(lambda z: z[:6] + '0' + z[6:])
    else: return df2.date.astype(str)

df2['new_date']=df2['date'].apply(date_changing)
```

There are other dates, so I'm trying to convert using an ‘if’ conditional to make things a little easier, but I get the following error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you include the error please?

Comment: sorry I forgot upload error code, here's my error code
I might think there's 2 errors occurred.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\generic.py", line 3826, in _set_item
    loc = self._info_axis.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'new_date'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

File "C:\ blocks.py", line 143, in __init__
    f"Wrong number of items passed {len(self.values)}, "
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1000, placement implies 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply function iterates row by row. Do not use the lambda function inside your function `date_changing`.

```
df2['date']=df2['date'].astype(str)

def date_changing(x) :
    if len(x) == 7: return x[:6] + '0' + x[6:]
    else: return x

df2['new_date']=df2['date'].apply(date_changing)
```

#Another Solution would be to use pandas.to_datetime

```
df2['date']=df2['date'].astype(str)
df2['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'], format = '%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check function from module `datetime` - [isoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat) or more general [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) function. These function will convert it to the expected format for you.

Answer (score 0):

Code to create the df:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
d = '''
Date
2020011 
20200101
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d))
df
```

Output:

```
    Date
0   2020011
1   20200101
```

Code to apply insert '0' into string:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: str(x) if len(str(x)) == 8 else str(x)[:6] + '0' + str(x)[6:])
```

Output:

```
Date
0   20200101
1   20200101
```

Comment: There was another way to solve this problem? Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help.